# Get files from the folder which were created yesterday

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Could you please advice me how to get a list of google spreadsheet URL in sub-folder by date creation - yesterday. Just a few words about what I need. Everyday I get new sub-folders created automatically with one or several files in it and have to collect some information from those files e.g. name of the file, URL, etc. I would like to set everyday trigger to get information from the previous day. I've tried to get information using this code but it doesn't work. Can you help me? And thank you in advance!

```
function listYesterdayFiles() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Jksajdhasdj123123klj");
  var files =folder.getFolders().next().getFiles();
  var result = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    result.push([file.getDateCreated()]);
 } 
  Logger.log(result);
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var now = new Date;
  var date= new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY);
  Logger.log(date)
  if (result = date);
  {var finalList = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    result.push([file.getDateCreated()],file.getName())}
  Logger.log(finalList);
  return finalList;// return most recent file ID
};
}
```

Comment: What about this approach: have a spreadsheet to record what you create daily (folders/sub, files etc...) and write the data (links, names, etc..) into the spreadsheet. You can then either have already the information needed into the spreadsheet, or check LastRow /? LastRow -1 to retrieve any other information you want to process